# Android setup onclicklistener in a for loop for multiple ImageButtons

Tags: android, onclick, nullpointerexception

I am pretty new to Android programming and I cannot figure out why my code will not get passed a certain line.  I have 26 pictures (the letters of the alphabet), and I want all of them to do something when I click on them, so I set up a for loop to set up an onclick listener for each one.  Whenever I run it on my phone and look at the log cat it says I have a null pointer exception and crashes.  If you look in the onCreate() method below, it gets to:

```
Log.d("LetterMenu Class", "for loop2");
```

but, it never reaches the

```
Log.d("LetterMenu Class", "for loop3");
```

or the

```
Log.d("LetterMenu Class", "before switch");
```

which is inside the onClick() method... So, apparently there is something it doesn't like about the way I am setting the OnClickListener (I am assuming), but I cannot seem to figure out what it is.  Can you set an OnClickListener using an array like that?  By the way, there are a lot more cases in the switch statement and it is closed correctly, I just didn't include that to save space. Thank you for any and all help.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class LetterMenu extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    String[] buttonNames = {"aButton", "bButton", "cButton", "dButton", "eButton",
            "fButton", "gButton", "hButton", "iButton", "jButton", "kButton", "lButton",
            "mButton", "nButton", "oButton", "pButton", "qButton", "rButton", "sButton",
            "tButton", "uButton", "vButton", "wButton", "xButton", "yButton", "zButton"};
    ImageButton[] letterButtons = new ImageButton[26];
    Intent intent;
    int res_id;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        Log.d("LetterMenu Class", "onCreate");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.letters);       

        for(int i = 0; i< 26; i++){
            res_id = getResources().getIdentifier(buttonNames[i], "id", getPackageName());
            Log.d("LetterMenu Class", "for loop");
            letterButtons[i] = (ImageButton) findViewById(res_id);
            Log.d("LetterMenu Class", "for loop2");
            letterButtons[i].setOnClickListener(LetterMenu.this);
            Log.d("LetterMenu Class", "for loop3");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d("LetterMenu Class", "before switch");
        switch(res_id){
        case R.id.aButton:
            Log.d("LetterMenu Class", "onClick1");
            intent = new Intent(this, Letters.class);
            intent.putExtra("LETTER_CLICKED", 'a');
            break;

        case R.id.bButton:
            intent = new Intent(this, Letters.class);
            intent.putExtra("LETTER_CLICKED", 'b');
            break;

        case R.id.cButton:
            intent = new Intent(this, Letters.class);
            intent.putExtra("LETTER_CLICKED", 'c');
            break;
```

Comment: `letterButtons[i] = (ImageButton) findViewById(res_id);` may return null because the `ImageButton of` the `res_id` couldnt be found. Where did you put those buttons?

Comment: Oh... Duh! I made a layout for all these buttons which was apparently horribly done because it attempted to allocate ao much memory that it crashed my S3 so i switched to a different layout to make sure that was the problem and then i started getting this problem instead because those buttons dont exist on that layout... Thank for you answering my question! I feel stupid now, but at least I know what I did wrong, lol.